# Cannot bootstrap due to clout-init "errors running cloud_config [final]: [scripts-user]"

Tags: juju, maas, cloud-init

I have installed maas server and configured juju also, And bootstrapped juju for 1st time, which I know will install zookeeper on 1 "ready" state VM available in MAAS.

So I observed this installation, it installed OS and the rebooted and came to this screen  and since then its stuck,

[image]

[image]

```
Error command failed: cannot inject a machine without a instance id
errors running cloud_config [final]: [scripts-user]
```

What are these errors? How can I resolve them? 
I am running 12.04.2 LTS, juju version is 1.13.1-precise-amd64 and maas version - 1.3.1

I also checked `juju status -v`, its gives following message continuously:

```
2013-08-08 16:31:17 INFO juju open.go:107 state: connection established
2013-08-08 16:31:17 INFO juju conn.go:64 juju: authorization error while connecting to state server; retrying
2013-08-08 16:31:17 INFO juju open.go:69 state: opening state; mongo addresses: ["pxp7m.master:37017"]; entity ""
2013-08-08 16:31:17 INFO juju open.go:107 state: connection established
2013-08-08 16:31:18 INFO juju open.go:69 state: opening state; mongo addresses: ["pxp7m.master:37017"]; entity ""
2013-08-08 16:31:18 INFO juju open.go:107 state: connection established
2013-08-08 16:31:18 INFO juju open.go:69 state: opening state; mongo addresses: ["pxp7m.master:37017"]; entity ""
```

Comment: its same error, here is output of bootsrap
juju bootstrap -v
INFO juju tools.go:75 environs: picked newest version: 1.10.0
INFO juju tools.go:25 environs: reading tools with major version 1
INFO juju tools.go:52 environs: filtering tools by series: precise
INFO juju tools.go:60 environs: filtering tools by version: 1.10.0
WARNING juju.environs.maas environ.go:230 picked arbitrary tools &{"1.10.0-precise-amd64" "http://192.168.34.20/MAAS/api/1.0/files/?key=37abd812-ff85-11e2-87f3-18a90577f7e4&op=get_by_key"}
INFO juju supercommand.go:276 command finished

Comment: I have tried bootstrap so many times, and still same issue.

Comment: This appears to be a cloud-init problem, not MAAS, I'll have one of them respond to your question!

Comment: If you could add the versions of Juju, MAAS, and Ubuntu to your question that would also be helpful, thanks!

Comment: hi jorge, thx alot! I am running 12.04.2 LTS, juju version is 1.13.1-precise-amd64 and maas version - 1.3.1

Comment: Problem is that i am reproducing this issue again and again, i don't even remember how many times now.

Comment: Or is this a bug?

Comment: @SaM The best way to add additional information to your question is by editing it, with the *edit* button. It is better visible that way, and comments are mainly for secondary, temporary purposes. Comments are removed under a variety of circumstances. Anything important to your question should be in the question itself.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i have no clue how, i followed same procedure - which i was using earlier and did everything again from scratch (might 6th or 7th time) and it worked, but i am suspecting there were few updates in juju package this time, which might have resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an issue with finding appropriate tools.  The juju client you said you were using was 1.13.1, but the tools it is finding is for 1.10.  These will almost certainly not work.

There is a sync-tools command that will get the latest tools from the public location to put into the local tools bucket.

Comment: Could you please elaborate how to solve this?

Comment: @Braiam There's a tool, `juju sync-tools` that you can use to pull/push tools